# Laravel 4: Get all product attributes with relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entity-attribute-value

I've got the following tables:

```
products (
    id
)

attributes (
    id
    name
    value
)

products_attributes (
    product_id,
    attribute_id
)
```

And I need to be able to query for all of the attributes of a specific product. I tried doing this with the FLUENT QUERY BUILDER but I'm getting lost in my own code.

Can someone help me out with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would create models for both of your entities, in which you can specify the relationships:

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Attribute', 'products_attributes');
    }
}

class Attribute extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'attributes';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'products_attributes');
    }
}
```

The `belongsToMany()` method sets up a many-to-many relationship. The first parameter specifies the related model class name, the second one the name of the database table that holds the connections between the two entities.

To find a product with ID 1234, you would fetch it like this:

```
$product = Product::find(1234);
```

You can then magically access all of its attributes like this:

```
$attributes = $product->attributes;
```

For more information, you can refer to [the documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).

Comment: I'd be careful with that, as Eloquent uses an internal `protected $attributes = array();` which will most likely break this.